# AngularJS- css doesnt load on browser reload using apache

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, apache

i am building a project using angularjs using html5 routing. I am serving it using apache. I have an issue: when i refresh the page, the css files specified in index.html doesnt load. 
I use this apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also i set base href to be '/'

Example of css : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/assets/styles.css">`

I also tried some configuration from other related questions and the solution didnt work out.
So i want to know if there is any solution or if anyone encountered this kind of issue.Any advice?

Comment: Just FYI: `base` only affects relative paths - `/assets/styles.css` is not relative, but absolute.

Comment: Could you be more specific please? i dont understand the difference

Comment: what is happening in browser dev tools network with them? Are you using html5mode in app?

Comment: The URL _assets/styles.css_ is relative to the current location (eg.: with _site.com/page_ it will point to _site.com/page/assets/styles.css_); the base element can be used to specify from where these relative URLs should start from. The URL _/assets/styles.css_ is relative do the domain and absolute regarding current location (eg.: folder) - same as using _base href="/"_ with an URL relative to current location. _http://www.example.com/assets/styles.css_ is an absolute URL, currently relative to the sol system.

Comment: Yes, i use html5 routing. In index.html i put all my script files(js / css) .When i refresh a page the css does not load from index.html.